# Is it ok that the drain line for a septic system is above ground?

Tags: septic

Looking to buy a property with mound septic.  The pipe coming out of the house going into the mound is above ground.  Is this ok?  Would the pipe not freeze?

Thank you.

Comment: Not if you're in a freezing climate (or have any aesthetic sensibility). Are you sure that's the case here? Maybe what you're seeing is a vent line or something. Photos would be great.

Comment: I'm not totally sure.  The pipe comes out of the house and goes directly into the mound.  I will try to get a photo.  Thank you

Comment: If you have a pumped system it will be on the surface. You don’t want the nozzles buried deep for when they get plugged and need to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem strange that the waste drain pipe goes straight out of the house above ground to the mound.  The primary purpose of the mound is for the distribution of water after it has passed through an enclosed septic tank and a pumping tank.  These two chambers are normally underground.  The pipes from the pumping stations would also be underground up to the mound and still would be buried in the mound as it travels to the top of the mound to the water distribution pipes.
I would have the owner explain where the septic tank and pump tanks are located and why the pipes you see are above ground.
Photos and more details on the pipes would be helpful.  Are these pipes on the surface of the ground?  What is the distance from house to mound? 
Is it OK, depends on whether a fully functional septic system has been installed.

Comment: Pipe is 2 ft above ground, approx. 4 ft. from mound.  My son came and looked at this house I was wanting to purchase and he said "no go" so I don't have to worry about it now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: 2 _feet_ above grade? Full stop.